# How to update value of an dataframe if it satisfies a specific condition inside a nested loop in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

[sammple data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWBcE.png)just need to know how can we update values inside a df with specific condition.

My Df contains some store related data, like store id, store name, Address, latitude, longitude ..
I need to find radius using this latitude and longitude

sqrt((x1-x2)^2) +((y1-y2)^2))

x1= 1st row latitude, x2 =2nd row latitude, like wise longitude also.
here I need to compare each store with other stores, so a nested loop.

So I converted Latitude and Longitude as lists and with the help of these 2 lists am doing the iteration
I have added new columns Radius and New_ID already

after running this the value of result is not getting updated in the dataframe,
please help me out,
If any more details required please let me know

```
while (i<latlist.length-1)
{
    j=1
    id=id+1    
        while(j<longlist.length)
        {
            result  = sqrt(pow(latlist(i)- latlist(j),2) + pow(longlist(i) - mylonglist(j),2))
            df3=df2.withColumn("Radius", col("Radius")+result)  

         }  j=j+1;   
         df4=  df3.filter(df3("Radius")<=1.32).withColumn("New_ID", col("New_ID")+id)     
        }
    i=i+1
}
```

df4.show(10)
}

Sample Data

StoreName   StoreReg    Latitude    Longitude   Radius  New_ID
Abc     MH      50.5684     6.9894      0   0
Xyz     DE      47.9783     7.4984      0   0
Pqr     AS      67.8479     10.7029     0   0
Qwr     LI      53.8733     8.8393      0   0
Dsg     GY      49.0832     9.78946     0   0
Hnr     TY      51.8937     8.5678      0   0
Erf     ER      52.7689     7.9763      0   0

Comment: Iterating rows in dataframes is almost never a good idea. Use a join.

Comment: Would be good to show a sample dataframe

Comment: can u please explain how can we do join for nested iteration?

Comment: Not adding up here, but leave it to mck

Comment: @Unnixlr8 You can do a self cross join on the two columns lat and long. Show some sample data and I can write an example in the answer

Comment: @mck i have added as an image, Please go through it and give me a sample answer

Comment: @Unnixlr8 please add sample data in text format, not as image format.